# DevExpress eXpressApp Framework (XAF) - Web Application customization

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

In XAF Windows Application I can customize Model at runtime using Model Editor. Is there any way to customize model at runtime when I use Web Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no web version of the XAF Model Editor.

You could create your own view controllers to allow a user to modify a specific aspect of the model at run time.  Or you could look at the [eXpand framework](http://www.expandframework.com/) which includes several modules which modify the model at runtime and which work with both XAF web and WinForms applications.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to shamp00 I will point you to this blog  http://apobekiaris.blogspot.com/2010/04/changing-your-web-model-at-runtime-with.html